# accessing the element of array and match it to the cell selected data

Tags: ios, swift

I have [image: ResturantFile.plist] where the restaurant names, items and price are stored in the form of 
(
{
Burger Point
(
{
itemName = 
ItemPrice = 
}
)
}
)

now i want to access the array elements and pass to RestaunrantViewController  when i select the collectionviewcell with corresponding name of each restaurant name, there is a UITableView in another viewcontroller and i want to display the itemName And ItemPrice.
but im not getting how can i done this

im accessing ResturantFile.plist using this

```
 let pathUrl =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ResturantFile", ofType: ".plist")
    print("path url is",pathUrl)

    let finalArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: pathUrl!)
    print("final Array is",finalArray)
```

And did select method code is :

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let pathUrl =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ResturantFile", ofType: ".plist")
    print("path url is",pathUrl)

    let finalArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: pathUrl!)
    print("final Array is",finalArray)

    let itemNames = finalArray?.sorted(by: {$0 == "ItemName"})// this is not working for me

    // pass restaurant name and image to the restaurntviewcontroller via viewcontroller
    if blockClosure != nil{ blockClosure(restaurantImageArray[indexPath.row] ,restaurantNameArray[indexPath.row] , data)
    }
}
```

this is my ResturantFile.plist

Comment: can you show me your CollectionView didselect method

Comment: first i was only passing the restaurant name and image via viewcontroller using closures

Comment: Update your question with this code

Answer (score 1):

In RestaurantViewController, You need to add filters using selected restaurant name like this *(replace "selectedRestroName" with your selected restaurant name which comes from the previous controller):*

```
let pathUrl = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ResturantFile", ofType: ".plist") print("path url is",pathUrl) 
let finalArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: pathUrl!) 
///finalArray is plish Data array, and "selectedRestroName" is the selected restaurant which is you passing from closure
    let selectedDict = finalArray.filter { (object) -> Bool in
        (object.keys).contains(where: {$0 == "selectedRestroName"})
    }.first

    let finalArraaOfSelectedRestorentData = Array(selectedDict!.values)
```

Or

```
let finalArraaOfSelectedRestorentData = selectedDict["selectedRestroName"]
```

Comment: but i want get the title from did select of collecion view and check for the finalArray with same title match and get those array

Comment: @GurjitSingh: updated my answer, you can get the title from the dictionary and add your functionality whatever you want on title

Comment: but in the restaurantNameArray there are only names of restaurants nothing else

Comment: restaurantNameArray is another  array which is not from plist data?

Comment: yes it is for dummy data for restaurant names, the original array name is finalArray which is from plist, can you give me a method to find the list for restaurant name as i got the restaurnt names from my blockclosure now i want to get the data for that restaurant.

Comment: it is now giving me the rest names but still not understanding the above code

Comment: You have to apply the filter on finalArray(which is coming from plist).  not on the restaurant name array.

Comment: filter like what we used in searchbar?

Comment: This is another question?

Comment: If you have many question then please update your question and add all question in well manner

Comment: Updated My Question

Comment: contains(where: {$0 == "selectedRestroName"}) // at where part

Comment: it was saying add <<args>>! somethng

Answer (score 0):

i got this done

```
func moveToDetailController(img:UIImage,name:String)
{
    print("the rest name is", name)

    let pathUrl =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ResturantFile", ofType: ".plist")
    print("path url is",pathUrl as Any)

    let finalArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: pathUrl!)
    print("final Array is",finalArray)

    let restaurantNames = finalArray?.firstObject as? NSDictionary
    print("resturant name is",restaurantNames as Any)


    if let menuDataArray:[[String:Any]] = restaurantNames?.value(forKey: name) as? [[String:Any]]
    {

        print("menu data is",menuDataArray)


    let restVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RestaurantViewController") as! RestaurantViewController

    restVC.tempImg = img
    restVC.tempTitle = name

    restVC.restMenu = menuDataArray

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(restVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

get the restName from previous by closure and then match the restName and get it into array and then pass the array to next controller and after that got the values into a dictionary and assign it by the key Value...